# Sort coordinates by proximity

Tags: gis, turfjs

I want to sort the coordinates by proximity. But since my target point is in it, the value returns 0. I am sharing my example code. I need to be able to sort all points by distance. It makes sense to do it by keeping it in an array and deleting the first point, but I haven't been able to.

I'll be happy if you can help me.

```
var targetPoint = turf.point([28.965797, 41.010086]);
var points = turf.featureCollection([
    turf.point([28.965797, 41.010086]),
    turf.point([28.973865, 41.011122]),
    turf.point([28.948459, 41.024204]),
    turf.point([28.938674, 41.013324])
]);

var nearest = turf.nearestPoint(targetPoint, points);
```

console.log(nearest["properties"]["featureIndex"]); //return 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the goal is. Your example code is pretty much the example code for [`nearestPoint`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#nearestPoint) with just the `targetPoint` added to the collection. Querying a collection of points for the nearest which also contains that same target point should just find that target point, which in your collection happens to be on index 0.

Anyway, sorting these points on distance to a target point can be done by generating a custom sorting function, and using it in the [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) of the the array of `Points` in the `FeatureCollection`.

This example does so in ascending order (closest to target first):

```js
function sortFeaturesByDistanceTo(target) {
    return function(a, b) {
    var options = {units: 'radians'}; // using radians to forgo conversion to another unit
    return turf.distance(target, a, options) - turf.distance(target, b, options);
  }
}

var targetPoint = turf.point([28.965797, 41.010086]);
var points = turf.featureCollection([
  turf.point([28.965797, 41.010086]),
  turf.point([28.973865, 41.011122]),
  turf.point([28.948459, 41.024204]),
  turf.point([28.938674, 41.013324])
]);

points['features'].sort(sortFeaturesByDistanceTo(targetPoint));

console.log(points);
```

To explain a bit more what is going on:

The function `sortFeaturesByDistanceTo(Point)` returns a new sorting function to use in `Array.sort()`.

The generated sorting function is called with 2 `Points` from the array to figure out which point should appear in the array before the other point. It simply returns the difference between the distance from `t` to `a` and the distance from `t` to `b`. A positive result means `a` should go first. a negative result means `b` should go first. 0 (zero) means no change should be made.

`Array.sort()` will call the generated sorting function multiple times, depending on the implemented sorting algorithm, until the array is sorted.

This means the distance for each point to the target will be calculated multiple times. A more optimal solution would calculate the distance for each point only once.

A `FeatureCollection` can be created with multiple types of features, and a `Point` is just one of such features. Sorting this way only works if the `FeatureCollection` only contains `Points`.

Please note that the output of this example is the same as the input, because the input array is already ordered.